# JQuery .each() loop is not actually looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I've upgraded the jQUery version in my project from 1.9 to version 2.0. After that I've got a strange problem in the following code:

```
var users = [];
        $('.users p').each(function (i, element) {
            var user= $(element);
            var person = {
                name: user.data('name'),
                birthdate: user.data('birthdate') || null,
                position: user.data('position') || null,
                id: user.data('id') || null
            };
            users.push(person);
        });
```

This is the  users html

```
<div class="users">
    <p>Test User<a class="delete ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" href="#delete">Delete</a></p>
    <p>Test user 25<a class="delete ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" href="#delete">Delete</a></p>
    <p>Test<a class="delete ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" href="#delete">Delete</a></p>
</div>
```

This loop was working perfectly but now when I add multple users to the `<p>` tags, it only takes the last user's details. Also its getting saved by the number of selected users count. For example: if I have selected 3 users and clicked save button, only the last user's details are getting saved 3 times.

Anyone know any fixes for this issue

Thanks

Comment: could you show some sample html ?

Comment: The code itself looks good to me. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I added the sample html

Comment: @FelixKling : Yeah it was a perfectly working code and this issue occured after the jquery upgrade

Comment: @FelixKling jsfiddle seems to be facing some problem for the last 1+ hours... not loading... do you have the same problem

Comment: You removed the data attributes for example sake or you really miss em?

Comment: @Arun: yeah, I have the same problem :-/ Too bad. Then I suggest http://jsbin.com/ ;)

Comment: @DanFromGermany well it wont getting showed in the html.